# Async Await doesn't work

Tags: javascript, async.js

So I have the following functions in Javascript which help me set my projectDetailsList state by querying a server for the list of projects and their details:

```
getProjectDetailsListHelper(){
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        await Object.keys(this.state.projectList).map(function (pid) {
            this.getProjectDetails(pid);
        }, this);
        console.log("getProjectDetailsHelperEnd");
    });
};

async getProjectDetails(project_id)
{
    const server = URL;
    await request
        .get(`${server}/get_project_details_compact?project_id=${project_id}&user=${this.state.user}`)
        .endAsync()
        .then(res => {
            console.log("getProjectDetails Start: ", res.body);
            let projDetailsListNew = this.state.projectDetailsList;
            projDetailsListNew[res.body.project_id] = res.body;
            this.setState(this.setProjectDetailsList(projDetailsListNew));
            console.log("getProjDetails End:", this.state.projectDetailsList);
            return null;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(JSON.stringify(err)));
};

setProjectDetailsList(projDetailsList){
    return (prevState) => {
        return {...prevState, projectDetailsList: projDetailsList};
    };
};
```

These are the logs:

```
>getProjectDetailsHelperEnd
>getProjectDetails Start:  
{status: 0, project_name: "Sample3", target: "Company1", creator: "agrawpri", timestamp: "2018-08-01 06:15:52", …}
>getProjDetails End: 
{3: {…}}
>getProjectDetails Start:  
{status: 1, project_name: "Sample2", target: "Company4", creator: "agrawpri", timestamp: "2018-08-01 05:57:11", …}
>getProjDetails End: 
{2: {…}, 3: {…}}
```

As you can see getProjectDetailsListHelper() doesn't wait for the map to complete but the getProjectDetails method works totally fine. What is the issue here?

Comment: `Promises` are async by default. Why you are explicitly doing that?

Comment: Also, other side, is async and not `await`ed

Comment: `getProjectDetails()` is asynchronous, it won't work inside `.map()`, even if you await it.

Comment: There are so many problems here I don't know where to start.... your problematic method *should* be something like `return Promise.all(Object.keys(this.state.projectList).map(getProjectDetails));` except that you don't return anything from that function, which includes a needless await for some reason? Chuck all this out and start over. And don't call `setState` in a loop! You're triggering a bunch of needless re-renders.

Comment: This comment may come across as rude, but I really don't mean it to be, so... disclaimer, etc. A few factors make this code look like you've copied and pasted multiple chunks from elsewhere, and it's apparent that you didn't really understand how they functioned. I don't think that, this code being in the state it is, we can reasonably provide much help. It would probably be better and faster if you started working through the code bit by bit and came back here with specific problems you are facing.

Comment: @FissureKing You're not wrong.  The OP has failed to provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The OP needs to edit and create an example that demonstrates the problem clearly.  Going back through and boiling the problem down to basics usually reveals the root problem anyway.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks! `return Promise.all(Object.keys(this.state.projectList).map(getProjectDetails));` worked!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Promise.all`, and return `Promise` from `map` callback

Change

```
getProjectDetailsListHelper(){
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        await Object.keys(this.state.projectList).map(function (pid) {
            this.getProjectDetails(pid);
         }, this);
        console.log("getProjectDetailsHelperEnd");
    });
};
```

into

```
async getProjectDetailsListHelper(){
    await Promise.all(Object.keys(this.state.projectList).map(function (pid) { // wait for all promises returned from map
        return this.getProjectDetails(pid); // return promise from getProjectDetails
    }, this));
    console.log("getProjectDetailsHelperEnd");
};
```

Comment: Sorry, but you realize the modified code will still never resolve, right? I didn't downvote but I would expect that was what earned it.

Comment: @FissureKing fixed now

Comment: Well, now you're not returning anything _and_ it's a syntax error. Try again :)

Comment: @FissureKing I don't need to return anything from async function to wait for it. Added `async` keyword :)

Comment: @ponury-kostek, you're absolutely right that you can `await` without assignment. I just assumed that a method beginning with `get` would return something but OP's apparently isn't returning anything either. Something tells me that is not the intention, however...

Comment: @FissureKing I know OP made many mistakes in his code, but I don't want to rewrite for him everything that is wrong. He need to learn by himself.